# OpenTelemetry Implementation in Single SPA react application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, open-telemetry

We are using a Single SPA framework in our application and planning to implement OpenTelemetry in our application. We use React for the front end and also using the BFF layer in Node Js to connect to the Back-End. Also, our Single SPA connects 6 micro front-end applications.

Here are a few questions.

1. Do I need to implement OpenTelementry on Individual Micro Front End applications or Implementing in a root-config of the single spa would be sufficient?
2. When I added OpenTelemetry in Root-config and Node JS(BFF) separately, we can see the traces under two services. One service is for the Front end and the other service is from NodeJs. But If we need to see the traces of connectivity from React to NodeJs, how can we achieve this?